# Whe choosing full disk encryption at installation, what method does Ubuntu use to erase the unused parts of the drive?

Tags: encryption

Does anyone know how Ubuntu secure erases the drive as part of encrypted installation?

I have this doubt that if the majority of the disk is zeroed, one might be able to predict the contents of parts of the the drive (zero fill) and therefore learn something about the encryption keys.

Can we assume that the system fills the drive with random bytes? What about areas of the drive with "known contents" perhaps like the boot loaders? How are those setup to prevent leaking information?

Comment: Does it do any free space overwriting at all? Last I read the cryptsetup faq advised it could be done manually before fs creation... if it is automatic it may slow installation a LOT. Creating a big file after install would accomplish the same thing

Comment: @Xen2050: Erasing free space is an option you can select at installation. The problem with creating a large file afterwards is that you have to fill the entire disk and having zero disk space is a good way to get a corrupted system. It would not be any faster either. I would also wonder about space 'reserved' by the OS - like swap - that can't easily be scrambled after installation. It's just quicker and more reliable to do it at installation.